# Не работает скрипт скрытия элементов строки по одному

Tags: javascript

Пробовал сделать так, чтобы элементы строки уменьшали свою прозрачность по одному, но я получаю ошибку

```
Cannot set property 'opasity' of undefined
    at main.js:11
(anonymous) @ main.js:11
```

Я понимаю, что где-то напутал с ссылками на данные, но не пойму, как исправить. Можете показать, как исправить ошибку?

```js
window.onload = function (){
 function fade(element, t) {
  var fps = 60;
  var time = t || 500;
  var steps = time / fps;
  var opasiti = 1;
  var d0 = opasiti / steps;

  var timer = setInterval(function () {
   opasiti -= d0;
   element.style.opasity = opasiti;
   steps --;
   
   if (steps === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
   }
  },(1000 / fps));
 }

 function doFade(DOMelement) {
  var element = document.getElementById(DOMelement);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < element.innerText.length; i++) {
   if(element.innerText[i] === " "){
    continue;
   }
   fade(element.innerText[i]);
   
  }

  console.log(element.innerText.length);
 }

 doFade('faded');





}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="faded">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia corrupti velit odio expedita harum magnam molestias beatae! Maiores quisquam et rem, molestias nesciunt consectetur amet nisi ipsam esse, veritatis minima?
 </p>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нет свойства `opasity`. Есть `opacity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `fade(element.innerText[i]);` - у функции `fade` два параметра. Какие? DOM-элемент и число? Зачем Вы туда букву передаете?
2. свойство называется `opacity`, а не `opasity`

```js
var oldText = $("#faded").text();
var newHtml = "";
for (var i = 0; i < oldText.length; i++) {
  if (oldText[i] != " ") {
    newHtml += "<span>" + oldText[i] + "</span>";
  } else {
    newHtml += oldText[i];
  }
}
$("#faded").html(newHtml);

var index = 0;
$("#faded span").each(function(){
  setTimeout(() => $(this).css("opacity", 0), 50 * (++index));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="faded">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia corrupti velit odio expedita harum magnam molestias beatae! Maiores quisquam et rem, molestias nesciunt consectetur amet nisi ipsam esse, veritatis minima?
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо!А как мне сделать чтобы каждая буква имела свойство `opacity`?

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov Завернуть каждую букву в `<span>`.

Comment: Если я заверну в `span` то каждая буква станет DOM єлементом и у нее появятся свойства.Получается мне в цикле нужно перед обработкой элемента совать его в `span`.Можете показать как засунуть в `span`  `element.innerText[i]`?